# How can I find the Maximum value in List<T> in .Net 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find the maximum value from the List objects.The class structure is

```
         public class SiteData
        {
             #region Fields
            private double? siteHeight;
            private double? siteWidth;

            #endregion



            #region Properties

            public double? SiteHeight
            {
                    get { return siteHeight; }
                    set { siteHeight = value; }
            }

            public double? SiteWidth
            {
                get { return siteWidth; }
                    set { siteWidth = value; }
            }
    }
```

Now i am having the function to find the Maximum SiteHeight.The signature of the function is

```
              public double FindMaxHeight(List<SiteData> objSite)
              {
               //logic to find the max. site height
               }
```

**I am using for loop to identify the maximum value and facing the performance issue....
.Net framework 2.0 - i am using right now**

Can anyone tell me how to find the maximum height without using for loop? is it possible?

Comment: Since you say you can't use a for loop, it sounds like homework. Tag it as homework if that is the case.

Comment: Since i am facing performance issue by using the foreach loop,i posted this question - Rajesh Kumar G

Comment: @Rajesh: would it be OK to use a while loop instead of a for loop, or is any type of looping construct not allowed?

Comment: What kind of performance issue are you facing? The complexity of finding `Max` in one dimensional unsorted array is of linear order `O(N)`.

Comment: @Matt : Is it possible to find the maximum value by using delegate?if not,post the answer using while loop

Comment: @Rajesh: accepted answer does not run faster than a simple loop over your data points.

Comment: @Rajesh: Why are you using Nullable values for **Height** & **Width**? Wouldn't it make better sense to simply initialize your **SiteData** object as NULL and have a constructor for your class initialize both the **Height** & **Width** to zero (0)? I don't know if there is more overhead to use Nullable values, but there is no reason for it that I can see. `K.I.S.S.` (Not calling you Stupid, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SiteData
{
    private double? siteHeight;
    private double? siteWidth;

    public double? SiteHeight
    {
        get { return siteHeight; }
        set { siteHeight = value; }
    }

    public double? SiteWidth
    {
        get { return siteWidth; }
        set { siteWidth = value; }
    }

    public static double FindMaxHeight(List<SiteData> objSite)
    {
        objSite.Sort(delegate(SiteData s1, SiteData s2) 
                                  {
                                      if (s1.SiteHeight > s2.SiteHeight)
                                          return 1;

                                      if (s1.SiteHeight < s2.SiteHeight)
                                          return -1;

                                      return 0;
                                  });
        return objSite[objSite.Count - 1].SiteHeight.Value;
    }
}
```

With List T:

```
    public static double FindMaxHeight<T>(List<T> objSite)
            where T : SiteData
    {
        objSite.Sort(delegate(T s1, T s2) 
                                  {
                                      if (s1.SiteHeight > s2.SiteHeight)
                                          return 1;

                                      if (s1.SiteHeight < s2.SiteHeight)
                                          return -1;

                                      return 0;
                                  });
        return objSite[objSite.Count - 1].SiteHeight.Value;
    }
```

Comment: So how is this faster than looping?

Comment: is it possible to make the above answer for List<T> ?

Comment: yeah..it is somewhat faster than for loop...i am satisfied

Comment: @alexl : are you there? is it possible to make the above answer for List<T>?

Comment: What you mean by List<T>, you should implement a interface to know how T will look like if you want to sort on it...

Comment: Check my answer maybe somethink like that but you can replace SiteData by an interface

Comment: @Axle : I want to find the maximum height and width by using your answer.Is it possible?    Since you r comparing only the SiteHeight property.

Comment: just do a FindMaxWidth method replacing Height with Width and you will have your two methods to get the max Height and the max Width

Comment: @alexL : so if the class contains "n" properties ,then i ll put "n" functions? any other way to implement it in one function?

Comment: but getting the max height and getting the max width are not same operations. Depends on your needs. You can do it with one method and work on your sorting requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add objects into a dictionary, that allows me to sort by height faster.

With all classic containers, there is a trade-off between rate of insertion and rate of retrieval.

This strategy makes sense when updates are rare, but you rely on the max value frequently.

You'd need to override GetHashCode() to return smaller numbers with larger heights.

I can see a little difficulty in that you'll have duplicates if your GetHashCode() is implemented that way.  You'll need to decide on precision, and not insert duplicates into your collection based on that fact.

Alternately, I'd use MultiDictionary from [PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/), and then rely on linear search pattern for the few readouts that are in the topmost bin.

```
internal int IndexForSortingBySiteHeight
{
   get
   {
      if(double.IsNaN(siteHeight) throw new ApplicationException();

      return (int)Math.Floor(siteHeight);
   }
}

public class ContainerForSortingBySiteHeight
{
    private List<SiteData> siteDataItems;

    public void Add(SiteData datum)
    {
        if(datum == null) return;

        siteDataItems[datum.IndexForSortingBySiteHeight] = datum;
    }

    public Max
    {
       get { return siteDataItems[0]; } // here's why a list won't work! What index should i use?
    }
}
```

Comment: in thi 2.0 .NET there is no LINQ

Comment: @GregC : I edited my question now...pls check it...also i have mentioned the Framework version in question itself

Comment: You code, and I can help you through the process when you get stuck.

Comment: @GregC: By using delegate ,it is not possible?

Comment: GetHashCode() is effectively a delegate for Dictionary that uses SiteData as key.

Comment: @Rajesh: what benefit do you think a delegate would bring? Are you thinking of using multi-threaded code?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather a strange way to do it, but you could do it with recursion.

You would create your initial function `double FindMaxHeight(List<SiteData> objSite)`

This would need to call a function that is a recursive function. A recursive function is one that causes itself to be called again, e.g.

```
int EnumerableLength(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    IEnumerator<T> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    return EnumeratorCount(enumertor, 0);
}

int EnumeratorCount(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int count)
{
    if(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        count++;
        return EnumeratorCount(enumerator, count);
    }
    else
    {
        return count;
    }
}
```

So you could move through your list like this, and comparing `(enumerator.Current as SiteData).SiteHeight` to the max height value you've currently got, and once you reach the end of the list you can return whatever the max is.

Comment: C# has no TCO.  I can already hear CLR saying "Stack Overflow Exception."

Comment: @GregC: Only if the list is *really* long. But yeah, I definitely wouldn't solve the problem this way, because in the real world I can use LINQ or loops.

Answer (score 1):

As GregC said, the optimization depends on what your common case is. If the list is fairly static and does not have item added often, you can sort the list on insertion. This flips insertion from O(1) to the complexity of your sort algorithm (there are a number of O(n log n) algorithms) and retrieval from O(n) to O(1). [How to use `List<T>.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)

I prefer keeping it in a list as opposed to a dictionary because the dictionary method adds extra meaning to the hashcode that most people won't expect. Where as there are already built-in methods to sort a list that are standardized and many people will know immediately.

Comment: The link that you have posted is sorting "string" class.how can i sort the list based upon the property of the class?

Comment: You'd provide an anonymous delegate or a function into the Sort() method that allows you to compare each one of the values.  You could say -1 if less than, +1 if greater than, 0 if equal.

Comment: It would run much slower than dictionary, since you'd have to sort completely on each insert.

Comment: @GregC : can u pls post the code using delegate?...I modified the return type of the property...its my mistake...i wrongly typed...

Comment: @RajeshKumarG: That is what the example uses, but if you read the page, you will see that it is using [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx).

Comment: @GregC: Optimization is always a balance of performance and readability. Just because you need better performance doesn't mean you need to go all the way to the optimal solution (the last 10% is 90% of the work). The OP needs to profile his code and see what his bottle-neck is an decide how much faster it needs to be.

Comment: it was stated in the question that a for loop won't do in terms of perf.  i took it for face value.

Comment: With that said, I am in a starch opposition to premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be iterating over the list using a for loop and checking the individual entries for the maximum height.

Another possible solution would be to implement the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) interface and sort the list of all items according to its height. The first item in the list after the sorting is the one you are looking for.

For a more advanced solution you could also use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method on the specified list and specify a delegate that will determine the item with the maximum height.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1. Yes, this is basically what I was about to say. This would be a more complete solution with a quick *How To:* section of code that uses **alexl**'s little bit of code above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Max method [msdn Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909073.aspx)

if this method doesn't present in 2.0 .Net I think is better to use for

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without loop if you have no kwnoledge about order of input sequence.
Show us your max value search code, maybe optimization is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to skip the for you can use the following method:

```
public double FindMaxHeight(List<SiteData> objSite)
        {
            objSite.Sort(new Comparison<SiteData>((x, y) => y.SiteHeight.Value.CompareTo(x.SiteHeight.Value)));
            return  objSite.Count > 0 ?  objSite[0].SiteHeight.Value : 0;
        }
```

or this one if there can be SiteData withoud siteHeight value

```
public  double FindMaxHeight(List<SiteData> objSite)
        {
            objSite.Sort(new Comparison<SiteData>((x, y)
                =>
                {
                    int xHeight, yHeight;
                    yHeight = y.SiteHeight.HasValue ? y.SiteHeight.Value : 0;
                    xHeight = x.SiteHeight.HasValue ? x.SiteHeight.Value : 0;
                    return yHeight.CompareTo(xHeight);
                }
            ));
            return  objSite.Count > 0 ?  objSite[0].SiteHeight.Value : 0;
        }
```

but I don't know if it will have better performance that the for loop. I will crono them, but it will be nice to know, how big or at least the approximate number of SiteData that your list will have!